# How to ensure only legitimate number is entered in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText, that already have `inputType` is `number`. This ensure only digit from `0-9` could be entered.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/uiEditTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

However, the problem is, user could still enter `000` or even `0123`, which doesn't look legitimate. I also want in such a way, when there's no character, it will return to `0` (instead of blank "")

I search on Stackoverflow, and found most question revolve around limiting the enter to using `android:inputType="number"`, but nothing mentioned how to avoid `00` or `0123` by auto convert them to `0` and `123`.

I made the function below, but seems hacky, where i have to manually change the text and move the cursor.

```
        uiEditTextNumber.doAfterTextChanged {
            if (it.isNullOrBlank()) {
                modifyText("0")
                return@doAfterTextChanged
            }
            val originalText = it.toString()
            try {
                val numberText = originalText.toInt().toString()
                if (originalText != numberText) {
                    modifyText(numberText)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                modifyText("0")
            }
        }

// ... AND the function

    private fun modifyText(numberText: String) {
        uiEditTextNumber.setText(numberText)
        uiEditTextNumber.setSelection(numberText.length)
    }
```

Any better solution out there?

**Note** the answer in [Is it possible to forbid the first number in a EditText to be "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24406447/3286489) is not helping, as it is just preventing the user from entering `01` and `0123`, but doesn't automatically change `0` to `1` when one type `1`. Besides, it also doesn't ensure when nothing is in the EditText, it automatically set to `0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: No, that's just to convert string to number. I know how to do that. I want to on the fly change my edittext entry to the legitimate number. I use `doAfterTextChanged`, but that will call `doAfterTextChanged` infinitely ... so I need to do some if-else check to stop the recursive run. Looks hacky

Comment: I have also ensure the entry is definitely 0-9 using the `inputType="number"`. So it's definitely no issue only getting number. But then, it doesn't prevent one from entering `00` or `0123`, which technical is a number, but it is not something anyone would enter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to forbid the first number in a EditText to be "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406447/is-it-possible-to-forbid-the-first-number-in-a-edittext-to-be-0)

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/q/24406447/3286489 is not answering it. I have updated my question to state why it is not answering.

Comment: I do think this is the best solution @Elye , so thanks for it and the Medium post :D

Answer (score 0):

to achieve your goal you can add the following function

```
fun removeLeadingZeros(strNumber: String): String {
        for (i in strNumber.indices) {
            val c = strNumber[i]
            if (c != '0') {
                return strNumber.substring(i)
            }
        }
        //If the number consists only from zeros, return zero.
        return "0"
    }
```

Then, when you need to get the text from the editText, you can call the function like so

```
str = removeLeadingZeros(strNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks. When will `removeLeadingZeros` be called? Isn't that kind of achieve by what I wrote above `val numberText = originalText.toInt().toString()`? Sorry, it still doesn't solve my inquiry of a better way not hacking it manually.

Comment: Hey, just updated my answer, you can call the function whenever you need to get the text from the editText

Comment: That's not answer my question of not to use `doAfterTextChanged`. I still have to resort to use `doAfterTextChanged` that doesn't seems to be ideal for my case.

Comment: I tried finding answers on google, looks like this question might be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406447/is-it-possible-to-forbid-the-first-number-in-a-edittext-to-be-0/24406700

Comment: Also, you didn't mention that you don't want a "do after text change", therefore I suggest you edit your question ;)

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406447/is-it-possible-to-forbid-the-first-number-in-a-edittext-to-be-0/24406700 is not answering as it is just toasting error, and not making it to be numeric.

Comment: I'm okay to use `doAfterTextChanged` if it doesn't need to do so many if-else within. So the problem is not `doAfterTextChanged`, and not how to convert String to Int. But how could we make EditText to dynamically like a calculator only accepting 0, 1, 2, 3... and not 01, 02, 003.

Comment: I'm confused, you said in your comment "That's not answer my question of not to use doAfterTextChanged."

Comment: However, the link I gave you is the exact question. They solved it by using input filter, which is the only way of making sure that the edit text doesn't accept a leading zero.

Comment: Doesn't accept leading zero is different from when the text is already "0", then when one key in "1", it should be "1" instead of "01". ... The answers in https://stackoverflow.com/q/24406447/3286489 is not helping. They just avoid type on when it is already "0". User have to explicitly remove 0 to type in other number, which is annoying.